# Shell How install local bulk of packages

Tags: 16.04, command-line, scripts, python, perl

I have 20 or 30 deb files within a folder in a local directory, lets say /home/Downloads. Given that the amount of files may vary, I need a script(or command or whatever) which installs all these .deb when executed. 
I have no knowledge of scripting on Linux, so the most explicit the answers the better.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a for loop:

```
cd ~/Downloads
for i in *.deb; do echo installing "$i"; sudo dpkg -i "$i"; done;
```

- `for i in *.deb` loop into all "deb" files
- `echo installing "$i"` print which one you are going to install
- Using `dpkg -i package` we install a "deb" package.

Hint: you can change `dpkg -i` with `gdebi` or `apt install` these options going to handle dependecies too (if any).

Comment: Really helpfull, this is what I was looking for. . Could not upvote the answer because of mi reputation. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful to you ;)